# missing required source folder: '.link_to_grails_plugins/tomcat-1.3.6/src/groovy'

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

sts2.6.0 release, grails1.3.7

work fine at commond run-app
but error warning at sts.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your project is set up to use Grails 1.3.6, but you trying to use 1.3.7.

Go to Preferences -> Grails and make the global default grails install become 1.3.7.  Alternatively, you can set the preference only for the single project.

Comment: grails upgrade catch problem when update tomcat plugin, some jar is using.